# JDBC won't update PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc

Working with Spring, PostgreSQL and JDBC. Database is set up, and I am successfully using JDBC to pull data from the database. When using a form to make a `POST`, however, the change doesn't go through. In debug mode, the correct attributes are present on the model, so I'm confident the error is in the database connection.

The form:

```
<form action="update-user" method="POST">
    <ul class="form-flex-outer">
        <li>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="${ currentUser.username }" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="${ currentUser.password }" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="${ currentUser.email }" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit changes" />
            <input type="hidden" value="${ currentUser.userId }" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/update-user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitUpdatedUserInformation(User user) {

    userDAO.updateUserInformation(user);

    return "redirect:/user-home";
}
```

The DAO method:

```
@Override
public void updateUserInformation(User user) {

    String sqlQuery = "UPDATE users " +
                      "SET username = ?, " +
                          "password = ?, " +
                          "email = ?, "  +
                          "updated_at = NOW() " +
                       "WHERE user_id = ?";

    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEmail(), user.getUserId());
}
```

I understand there are configurations in the `springmvc-servelet.xml` file concerning transactions, but I have worked with JDBC in the past without trouble.

User creation from DB init:

```
CREATE USER app_owner WITH PASSWORD 'app_owner1';
GRANT ALL 
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
TO app_owner;

GRANT ALL 
ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public
TO app_owner;
```

Comment: Does the method `submitUpdatedUserInformation` get called and if so what is the value of user.user_id ?

Comment: Where's the *exact text of the error message* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
<input type="hidden" value="${ currentUser.userId } }" />
```

be

```
<input type="hidden" value="${ currentUser.userId }" name="userid" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't `} }"` be just `}"` also?

Comment: oh yes @a_horse_with_no_name careless of me copy pasted and added my 2c

Comment: Thanks so much @e4c5 - I was forgetting to pass the userId into the controller as a form.